# In Function Apps, is the unit of scale the Function or the App?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

If I have to units of work `Foo` and `Bar`, will Azure be able to scale them independently if I have them both in one app

```
MyFunctionApp
   FooFunction
   BarFunction
```

or can they only scale if in different apps

```
   MyFooFunctionApp
       FooFunction

   MyBarFunctionApp
       BarFunction
```

On a related note, if I'm using [Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview), e.g.

```
    var x = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("F1");
    var y = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("F2", x);
    var z = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("F3", y);
    return  await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("F4", z);
```

then do the functions `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, `F4` have to be in the same app or can they be functions in different apps?

Answer (score 3):

Function App is the unit of scale. All functions within an app will scale together.

All Functions of a Durable Functions App should stay within the same Function App.

Answer (score 3):

The unit of scale for Azure Functions is the **Function App**. This effectively means that if any individual function in your app needs to scale-out, then all functions in your function app will scale out together.

To answer your Durable Functions question (which should probably be a separate question), they all need to be the same function app. You can find more discussion on this topic, including workarounds, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/156).